# React Native:call a function component within the same class

Tags: react-native

I am converting a function component to class component in React Native 0.62.2 app. There are a few function components are defined within the function component. After converting to class component, there is error with those function components defined. The error is:

```
[ReferenceError: Can't find variable: GridImage]
```

Here is the code example:

```
export default DisplayImg extends React.Component {

   GridImage = () => {
     //component detail
   };

   render() {
     return (
     <GridImage .../>
     );
   }
```

}

I probably can convert `GridImage` to a function and call it in the same class. But is there a way to call function component defined within the same class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference the function using `this`

```
render() {
 return (
  <this.GridImage .../>
 );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class App extends React.Component {
  GridImage = () => <p>GridImage</p>;
  render() {
    return <React.Fragment>
      <this.GridImage />
    </React.Fragment>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
</script>
```

or just call the function in your render

```
render() {
 return (
   // this's better than the above approach
  {this.GridImage()}
 );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class App extends React.Component {
  GridImage = () => <p>GridImage</p>;
  render() {
    return <React.Fragment>
      {this.GridImage()}
    </React.Fragment>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that Funcional (or class) components cannot be created inside other components. Just move them to the same file or to its own one.

Remember, functions always start with lower case and you can create them inside components, or outside of course. Components, instead, start with upper case and can’t be created inside other components (if they only have sense or will be used in this unique component then declare it in the same file and do not export it).

And a recommendation (a good pattern from the book React Patterns from Packt) is to declare functional components as follow:

```
   function Component(props) {...}
```

and not as an arrow function.

Comment: Also make sure you return nodes from your component.